# Improve PySpark job analyzing data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

I have some JSON files in a Google Storage with a big amount of data (between 500GiB and 1TiB). These files contain 1 JSON object per line with the following format:

```
{"country":"US", "col1":"val1", "col2":"val2", "col3":"val3"}
{"country":"CA", "col1":"val4", "col2":"val5", "col3":"val6"}
```

My goal is to make different tables in BigQuery for the 10 countries I can find in this data. So I would end up with 10 tables, one for example would be named `data_us` with the schema: `col1,col2,col3`.

The way I'm currently doing it is to use PySpark and run the job on a cluster of machine on Google Dataproc:

```
    data = spark.read.json(bucket_source)
    data.createOrReplaceTempView('data')

    for c in country_list:
        table_name = "data_{}".format(c)
        query = "select col1, col2, col3, from data where language = '{}'".format(c)
        result_folder = "result_{}".format(c)
        result = spark.sql(query)
        push_bigquery(bucket_dest, cluster_name, project_name, dataset_name, result, result_folder, table_name)
```

So basically, I just load the data, create a view and ask PySpark to run 1 request for each country. Then I call the `push_bigquery` function which just dumps the result to CSV files and loads them into BigQuery. This solution works but it seems kinda slow for big amount of data (around 12 hours for data size close to 1TiB).

I have 2 questions:

- I'm currently running 1 query per country, so the whole data gets analyzed for each query. Is there a way to just "analyze" each line and to write it immediately in the right result/file ? I feel like it would be faster but as I'm not very familiar with Spark/PySpark yet I don't know if this solution makes sense.
- Is there a completely different and better way to do this task than using Spark?

Thank you for your help

Comment: 1 TB is not a big amount these days

Answer (score 0):

I miss .cache but the following would be my first attempt based on N country <-> N table requirement:

1. No caching.
2. Read, re-partition and write out in non-parquet (no need for columnar) form via `df.repartition(country).write...partitionBy(country)...` with appropriate options.
3. Then I would apply your for loop per country relying on partition awareness, of you do want separate tables, for which has to be said, this is not entirely necessary. I.e. Step 2 would suffice in general.

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize it using the code provided by @thebluephantom
and a bit more by doing this.

```
df.repartition(country).write...partitionBy(country)
```

And after saving your dataframe, now you will have individual folders for every country.
So while running your bq load command, you can create your country level tables on these folders. In this way you don't need to do any further processing and you will have separated data fro all your big query tables.